# Is there a way to receive all wild card emails programatically?

Tags: outlook-restapi, mailkit

For example, I have a domain named `foo.com`. I created the following email addresses:

- sales@foo.com
- hr@foo.com

I need to listen to all email addresses created from the `foo.com` domain.

Also, I am the owner of the `foo.com` domain.

Can I create an Imap Idle Client that will listen for all wild card email addresses?

I am also looking into outlook mail REST API for this.

Please let me if there is any API that will listen for all email address in a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Mailkit` approach, I have learned that I will have to create an `Imap client` for each email address. There is no other way.

`Office 365 API` allows me to read all emails within an `organization`. I will need to create a multitenant application in Azure AD and allow `Read Mail in All mailboxes`.

After that, I need to check `admin_consent only`.

[Best way to get emails in an organization using the Outlook 365 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609058/best-way-to-get-emails-in-an-organization-using-the-outlook-365-api)